Script all functions in PostgreSQL
How can I extend this to script out every function in a DB?
select pg_catalog.pg_get_functiondef('my_function_name ()'::regprocedure::oid);
I would like to generate a script with the definition of every function in Postgres 15 DB.

You can use something like this, using pg_proc:
SELECT nspname AS schemaname
    , proname AS function_name
    , pg_catalog.pg_get_functiondef(pg_proc.oid)
     , pg_get_function_arguments(pg_proc.oid)
    , pg_proc.*
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON pronamespace = pg_namespace.oid
WHERE relkind <> 'a' -- no aggregate functions!
ORDER BY nspname, proname, proargnames;

To support aggregate functions, you have to join on pg_aggregate and get the source code for each part of the aggregate.
